# Grid or dots on white image on ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-glide

I display image on ImageView using Glide and on white parts there is strange grid/dots:

[image]

Images themselves doesn't have them:

[image]

I am not using any wired stuff:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Load image:

```
imageView.loadImage(news.imageUrl)

fun ImageView.loadImage(photoUrl: String) {
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(photoUrl)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(this)
}
```

Here is whole app code:

https://github.com/MarcinMoskala/KotlinAcademyApp/tree/master/android/app

Answer (score 0):

Use DiskCacheStrategy.NONE (for local images) or DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE (for remote images) to prevent Glide from re-compressing the images:

```
Glide.with(this)
    .load(url)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer: I had to separate image and background with border!

[image]

Code used to add frame is here:

https://github.com/MarcinMoskala/KotlinAcademyApp/blob/3c6e282a652220a2dfd8667265d576929e12ad4e/android/app/src/main/java/com/marcinmoskala/kotlinacademy/ui/common/ViewExt.kt

Comment: Since this concludes the issue, I think it would be a good idea to post the code used in the solution, or if the solution was to add a border to the actual image file, in that case explain it in the post. Just a screenshot does not explain a lot to someone searching for the same issue.